# Viewpager inside BottomsheetdialogFragment not showing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have implemented BottomSheetDialogFragment into **OptionsFragment**.In which I have added viewpager so I can do swipe animation for SignInSignUpOptionsFragment which I want to add in viewpager and button to Swipe SignInSignUpOptionsFragment with different option. SignInSignUpOptionsFragment has options of Login(+ social accounts).

AccountFragment

```
  login_btn.onClickListener( v -> { 
  OptionsFragment optionsFragment = new OptionsFragment(true);
  optionsFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Login");
  });
```

OptionsFragment

```
  class OptionsFragment(private val isLogin: Boolean) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private var fragmentView: View? = null
lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_popover, container, false)
    val pagerAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    viewPager = fragmentView!!.findViewById(R.id.vpPager)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    viewPager.currentItem = 0
    return fragmentView
}

}

  class MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
// Returns total number of pages
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return NUM_ITEMS
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
   return when(position) {
        0 ->  SignInSignUpOptionsFragment.newInstance(true)
        1 ->  SignInSignUpOptionsFragment.newInstance(false)
        else -> null!!
    }
}

// Returns the page title for the top indicator
override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return "Page $position"
}

companion object {
    private const val NUM_ITEMS = 2
}
```

here's my layout file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/utilityGrey2">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_no_account_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vpPager">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_sign_up_description"
        style="@style/HelpText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_account" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_sign_up"
        style="@style/HelpText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_caps" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but I am not able to see any fragment inside ViewPager. Only bottom **"login_no_account_group"** is displaying as Bottomsheet. I don't want to use  TabLayout, instead I want to change page on switch_sign_up click

```
   viewPager.currentItem = 1
```

Is it possible ? any other alternative welcome as well

Comment: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"` – It seems like your `<ViewPager>` would be completely off-screen. Try adjusting it's layout positioning, and make sure that you can see it on-screen at runtime.

Comment: that's correct. ohh that was biggest mistake now at least other layout start showing on view pager though slide animation not there yet. but Thanks